# putObject: TimeoutError: Timeout in AWS Glue while trying to read parquet files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am trying to read all the parquet files one by one from a S3 bucket, update the mapping of the files and write them in a target location.
I would not know the actual count of the files in the s3 bucket and hence am using the below code to know the number and names of the files:

```
fileList = []
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
myBucket = "test-bucket"
objs = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=myBucket, Prefix='', Delimiter='/')

print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
print(objs)
for prefix in objs.get('CommonPrefixes'):
    folder = prefix.get('Prefix')
    resp = s3_client.list_objects_v2(
        Bucket=myBucket,
        Prefix="test_actual_files/" + 'lrf/bus_dt=20200818/',
    )
if resp.get('Contents') is not None:
    for obj in resp.get('Contents'):
        print("+++++++++++++++++++++File Names++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        filePath = obj.get('Key')
        fileName = filePath.split('/')[-1]
        fileList.append(fileName)
        print(fileList)

#get the number of files
length = len(fileList)

for i in range(length):
    print(fileList[i])
```

Using the above code I am able to figure out the files that are present in the s3 bucket location.

After knowing the file names, I want to read the files in the location using glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options as below:

```
S3bucket_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="s3",
    format="parquet",
    connection_options={
        "paths": ["s3://test-bucket/test_actual_files/lrf/bus_dt=20200818/"],
        "recurse": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1",
)
```

However when I add the above glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options code I start getting the below error:

```
putObject: TimeoutError: Timeout
```

Is there something that I am missing. I can read the s3 bucket and get the file names but am getting this issue while trying to read the contents of

I tried using python code in order to read the files and create a source to target mapping and want implement this solution using Glue dynamic frames